# Setting a static variable to a function php class

Tags: php, oop

I'd like to set the value of my static variable to a function. But the __construct never runs with static calls. So what's an alternate route I can do to set this variable so I can re-use it many times in my class?

```
function sayhey(){
    return 'hey';   
};

// my class i do control
class Class1 {

    private static $myvar;
    
    public function __construct(){
        self::$myvar = sayhey();
    }
    
    public static function func1(){
        echo '<pre>'; print_r(self::$myvar); echo '</pre>';
    }

}// end class

// how can i make this work if the __construct never runs for static calls?
Class1::func1();

// obviously this works
//$class1 = new Class1();
//$class1->func1();
```

Comment: Don't you think that you have some bad design if you have a static class but need a constructor? Maybe class should not be static then?

Comment: @u_mulder There's no such thing as a static class, it's a static property.

Comment: The problem he's having is that the initial value of a static property has to be a constant, you can't calculate it dynamically.

Comment: My fault, should be - method shoud be not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
function sayhey(){
    return 'hey';   
};

// my class i do control
class Class1 {

    private static $myvar;
    
    public function __construct(){
        self::$myvar = sayhey();
        //echo '<pre>11 '; print_r(self::$get_cart_contents); echo '</pre>';
    }
    
    public static function func1(){
        echo '<pre>'; 
        self::$myvar = self::$myvar ?? sayhey(); 
        print_r ( self::$myvar );
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}// end class

Class1::func1();
```

Comment: Thanks I like this cause its simple. Does self::$myvar ever really get set? I added a func2() and tried to see if it ever gets populated by func1 but it doesn't so maybe there's not a point in a check to see if self::$myvar ever gets set? 

Instead maybe i should just do $myvar = sayhey(); and reuse for my multiple class sections

Comment: No it does not set the value. It came to my mind to serve the value and also use that function  as setter  when  you will initialize the class .that's why i used the null coalescing operator. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need at some point to initialise the static property.  As the constructor is useless for static methods, this 'replaces' the work done by creating an `init()` method (also static) which is called when `self::$myvar` is null (using `self::$myvar ?? self::init()`...

```
function sayhey(){
    return 'hey';
};

// my class i do control
class Class1 {
    
    private static $myvar;
    
    public static function init(){
        self::$myvar = sayhey();
        return self::$myvar;
    }
    
    public static function func1(){
        echo '<pre>'; print_r(self::$myvar ?? self::init()); echo '</pre>';
    }
    
}// end class

// how can i make this work if the __construct never runs for static calls?
Class1::func1();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also save the function name in the variable instead of the result of the call.

```
function sayhey(){
    return 'hey';   
};

class Class1 {

    private static $myvar;
    
    public static function set($fct){
        self::$myvar = $fct;
    }
    
    public static function func(){
      $result = (self::$myvar)();
      return $result;
    }

}

Class1::set('sayhey');
echo Class1::func();  //hey
```

I suspect [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.traits.php) are better.

```
trait myfunctions{
  public static function sayhey(){
    return 'hey';   
  }
}

class Class1 {
  use myfunctions;
}

class Class2 {
  use myfunctions;

  public static function fct1(){
    return self::sayhey();
  }
}

echo Class1::sayhey();  //hey
echo Class2::sayhey();  //hey
echo Class2::fct1();  //hey
```